# Google Play Developer API: Wrong currency for subscription

Tags: google-play, google-play-services

I am working on tracking Google Play subscriptions in a data warehouse. After validating the data with App Figures (which is based on Google's financial reports) we found that the data for foreign countries was way off. Actually, we were wrongly tracking that most of our purchases were made in *USD* (our default).

We did some research and found that, sometimes, the values of **priceCurrencyCode** and **countryCode** don't match. Find here an example:

```
{
 "kind": "androidpublisher#subscriptionPurchase",
 "countryCode": "IT",
 "developerPayload": "",
 "autoRenewing": false,
 "priceCurrencyCode": "USD",
 "expiryTimeMillis": "1456733642426",
 "cancelReason": 1,
 "startTimeMillis": "1409472846296",
 "priceAmountMicros": "4990000"
}
```

As you can see, **since the purchase was made in Italy**, I would expect the **currency code to be in Euros**, and not USD. Obviously, **priceAmountMicros** is also wrong, and linked to USD, not Euros.

I was wondering if anybody else has experienced this issue, and if there is something else I am not understanding or it's just Google API being buggy and falling back to our default currency.

Comment: Try to use the [getSkuDetails()](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#getSkuDetails) method from In-app Billing Version 3 API. It's price' key includes the formatted price of the item, including its currency sign. So if price is specified in British pounds sterling, price_currency_code is "GBP", etc.

Comment: Thanks, I was already doing at (though through the REST API). The problem is different though. It is that I cannot rely on the **priceCurrencyCode** that the subscription endpoint returns, because it is not right. What I'm currently doing to fix it, is taking the **countryCode** (which seems to be correct) and then using the SkuDetails endpoint to choose the currency.

Comment: Good to know you've got it working.